# Is there a function to get the unpublish info of a page in Tridion CoreService?

Tags: c#, sdl, tridion, tridion-core-services

I need to get the last time that a page was unpublished.
I know that exist a CoreService method called GetPublishInfo, but it's only returns the publish information not the unpublish.

```
// shows the publish information 
client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
client.Open()
client.GetListPublishInfo(tcmPage);
```